# Network is unreachable - Ports Socket Client

Tags: centos7

I have an application in PHP, which creates a client (socket client) that connects to another site (a server client - socket).

In fact, I have several applications (30 or 50 more) that do this on the same server.

The point is, I can't connect a new client (from error: network unreachable)

> stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> tcp://[2606:4700:10::6814:da43]:443 (Network is unreachable)

Is this some centOS7 configuration?

In fact, it seems that the client works, the connection happens, but this error is triggered .. I don't know if any configuration is missing.

What can I be doing?

Comment: Check your internet connectivity.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the network is working, the connection is ok. I test: "curl -I https://linuxconfig.org", and return 200 HTTP

Comment: But did you run it with `-6`? After all, it is clearly your IPv6 connectivity that needs to be checked.

Comment: @MichaelHampton nice! not works, "send failed", when i trigger: "tracepath6 ipv6.google.com"... How did you detect that it was an IPV6 connectivity problem? Would you have any suggestions on what to do now?

Comment: It was obvious because your error message shows that you cannot connect to an IPv6 address. The next thing to do is to figure out why IPv6 is broken. What sort of machine is this? What network is it connected to?

Comment: @MichaelHampton When i trigger the command: "ping6 ipv6.google.com" show: "Network is unreachable".. Nice, is the same error.. Machine is CentOS 7, But i dont know about "what network is it connected"..

Comment: Certainly it doesn't exist in the void! It must be hosted somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did not understand what you meant .. If I can be more direct, I am a layman in this matter.

Comment: It is somewhere on planet Earth (presumably)! It is owned and hosted by someone. Who and where?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't think it was relevant to talk about where my service is. But it is a local hosting, "VirtusHost", it is a "High Performance Cloud", KVM 8GB, any information you need to know more about? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHampton My server does not have IPV6 support, only 4. There is an explanation, why can I still connect to IPV6? I can take over a connection (although it sometimes fails) ..

Comment: I've tried to reach your provider's web site for a couple of days and it's so slow that it never even loads completely. I can go to other web sites in Brazil and they are fast, so I think something is generally wrong with your host. Anyway, if your server isn't supposed to have IPv6 support, then no programs on it should be trying to reach IPv6 addresses. The host has probably done something wrong here, for example giving you an IPv6 address when they haven't enabled IPv6. Check your server's network configuration to see if it got a global IPv6 address or route, i.e. `ip a` and `ip -6 r`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You see the correct Host? www.virtushost.net/ .. Good to know, would you recommend, DigitalOcean, Vultr? I mean, for some time I think about it, I believe that other Hosts "less controllers", where I will be more sure of the service I purchased.

Comment: Yes, www.virtushost.net, it takes almost 10 minutes for their web site to load, and even then some of the images and CSS are missing. I've not heard of them before. If you expect most of your traffic to come from South America then hosting in Brazil makes sense, regardless of which provider you choose. I don't know if Digital Ocean or Vultr offer servers physically located in Brazil.

Comment: @MichaelHampton In fact, my preference is in North America, basically my applications connect there. I think I will think about it better, I already have days thinking about changing servers, I mean, for one that seems a little more independent and of great name, that's why I asked DigitalOcean or Vultr, they have a lot of content also to support. Thank you for support, Eliminating the host issue, which honestly bothers me, the problem will be just me with the server.